# Enable label when a button is clicked

Tags: jquery

I have problem with jQuery. I have one button, one label, and one div.

When I click on the button, then the label fires. "button click" and "registereduserlabel" enabled means then I want to show "RegisteredUser" div.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        if ($('#<%=btnSave.ClientID %>').click(function () {
            if ($('#<%=lblRegisteredUser.ClientID %>').prop('enabled', true)) {
                $('#<%=RegisteredUser.ClientID %>').show();
                $('#<%=btnCreateAccount.ClientID %>').hide();
            };
        }));
    });
</script>
```

Comment: how can you enable/disable a label..?

Comment: I meant label fire event when I click on the button .

Comment: what do you mean by ` label fire event` ..?

Comment: What you mean by "When I click on button, then the **label fires**"?

Comment: When I clicked on the button , the label shows some message after that the div will be show . So "button click" and "label shows" occurs only the div will be show.  2."button click" and "label Not shows" occurs, the div will not be show.

Comment: please someone help me to do the above code .

Answer (score 0):

use disabled attribute instead of enabled in jquery

```
if (!$('#<%=lblRegisteredUser.ClientID %>').prop('disabled')) {
    $('#<%=RegisteredUser.ClientID %>').show();
    $('#<%=btnCreateAccount.ClientID %>').hide();
};
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24382706/enable-label-when-button-click-jquery#comment37709515_24382706

Answer (score 0):

try changing

```
       if ($('#<%=lblRegisteredUser.ClientID %>').prop('enabled', true))
```

to

```
     if ($('#<%=lblRegisteredUser.ClientID %>').prop('enabled') == true)
```